# Как мне увеличить память на диске при помощи другого диска на ubuntu сервере

Tags: linux, ubuntu, devops, lvm

У меня есть диск /dev/vda с разделом /dev/vda1.
Мне нужно увеличить его размер, для этого я добавил еще один диск /dev/vdb.
Инструкции, которые я нашел в интернете, описывают способы расширения /dev/vda1 при помощи /dev/vda2, но у меня добавляется на сервер именно диск, а не раздел, поэтому этот способ мне не подходит. Еще есть способ копирования данных с /dev/vda на /dev/vdb, но хотелось бы просто увеличился размер /dev/vda1.
Я в администрировании не силен, по-этому хотелось бы узнать какие еще есть способы расширить память и возможно ли вообще это сделать. (и нужно это сделать с сохранением данных с /dev/vda1)

Пробовал эту инструкцию для первого способа.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/66000/how-to-merge-partitions

Пробовал эту инструкцию для второго способа.

1. Подготовка нового диска:

   - Подключите новый диск /dev/vdb к вашей системе (например, вставьте его в свободный слот или подключите внешний диск).
   - Создайте раздел на новом диске с помощью утилиты  `fdisk`  или  `parted` . Например, выполните следующую команду:
     sudo fdisk /dev/vdb
     Затем создайте новый раздел, выбрав опцию "n", и следуйте инструкциям по созданию раздела.
   - Создайте файловую систему на новом разделе. Например, для создания файловой системы ext4, выполните следующую команду:
     sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/vdb1
2. Монтирование нового диска:

   - Создайте временную точку монтирования, где мы будем монтировать новый диск. Например:
     sudo mkdir /mnt/newdisk

- Монтируйте новый диск в созданную точку монтирования:
  sudo mount /dev/vdb1 /mnt/newdisk

3. Копирование данных с корневого диска на новый диск:

   - Скопируйте все данные с корневого диска на новый диск с помощью команды  `rsync` . Например:
     sudo rsync -avx / /mnt/newdisk
     Эта команда скопирует все файлы и папки с корневого диска в новый диск, сохраняя атрибуты и разрешения файлов.
4. Обновление конфигурации:

   - Откройте файл  `/etc/fstab`  с помощью текстового редактора:
     sudo nano /etc/fstab

- В этом файле найдите строку, связанную с корневым диском (обычно это будет  `/`  или  `/dev/vda1` ). Измените устройство на новый диск, например,  `/dev/vdb1` .

  - Сохраните изменения и закройте файл.

5. Перезагрузка и проверка:

   - Перезагрузите систему:
     sudo reboot

Comment: Собственно, последняя метка вопроса и является ответом на вопрос

Comment: А lvm позволит мне добавить в группу диск с системой? Я пытался, но вылезала ошибка. Хотя может это не связано? Я постараюсь воссоздать ошибку

Comment: Сложный вопрос, даже если вдруг и можно, одно неверное движение и данных нет. Я бы сделал бэкап, переустановил бы всё нафиг с нуля и развернулся бы ис бэкапа (впрочем, если уж переустанавливаться, то можно и заодно поставить один большой диск вместо двух маленьких)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Порядок действий для перехода к lvm такой. Подключаете второй диск. Ставите на нем pv, vg и lv размером чуть больше системного. Останавливайте все сервисы или перезагрузитесь в single user. Скопируйте содержимое системного диска на новый том, уже в lv. Сделайте чрут в новый образ , настройте граб на загрузку с lvm (надо параметр добавить при grub-install. Потом перезагружайтесь со второго диска. Форматируйте первый в pv, добавляйте в vg и растягивайте lv на оба диска. Потом растянуть файловую систему до размера.

Делал такое на днях. Очень заморочисто. Легче поставить с нуля